# How to Remove unique code identifier in a file

Tags: android

This is the file i downloaded, I wanted to remove those unwanted prefix when I save them in my external storage after downloading ef17a39f-4f65-4dcd-b3d7-0d69eab17042-reminder_suprep_second_dose.mp3 PLEASE HELP!

Comment: You can use a miraculous new function called substring (http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#substring%28int%29)

Comment: Can you please change the subject to '... remove from file name' ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

String substr = mysourcestring.subString(37, yourString.length());

subStr would be your cropped string.